# How to store actix_web Json to mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, rust, actix-web

Trying to store incomming data into mongo using r2d2-mongodb and actix_web.

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Weight {
    desc: String,
    grams: u32,
}

fn store_weights(weights: web::Json<Vec<Weight>>, db: web::Data<Pool<MongodbConnectionManager>>) -> Result<String> {
    let conn = db.get().unwrap();
    let coll = conn.collection("weights");
    for weight in weights.iter() {
        coll.insert_one(weight.into(), None).unwrap();
    }
    Ok(String::from("ok"))
}
```

I can't seem to understand what/how I need to convert weight into to use with `insert_one`.
The above code errors into `error[E0277]: the trait bound 'bson::ordered::OrderedDocument: std::convert::From<&api::weight::Weight>' is not satisfied`

Answer (score 1):

The [signature for `insert_one`](https://docs.rs/mongodb/0.9.0/mongodb/struct.Collection.html#method.insert_one) is:

```rust
pub fn insert_one(
    &self, 
    doc: Document, 
    options: impl Into<Option<InsertOneOptions>>
) -> Result<InsertOneResult>
```

`Document` is `bson::Document`, an alias for [`bson::ordered::OrderedDocument`](https://docs.rs/bson/0.14.0/bson/ordered/struct.OrderedDocument.html).

Your type `Weight` does not implement the trait `Into<Document>`, which is required for `weight::into()`. You could implement it, but a more idiomatic way would be using the `Serialize` trait with `bson::to_bson`:

```rust
fn store_weights(weights: Vec<Weight>) -> Result<&'static str, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let conn = db.get()?;
    let coll = conn.collection("weights");

    for weight in weights.iter() {
        let document = match bson::to_bson(weight)? {
            Document(doc) => doc,
            _ => unreachable!(), // Weight should always serialize to a document
        };
        coll.insert_one(document, None)?;
    }

    Ok("ok")
}
```

**Notes:**

1. `to_bson` returns an enum, [`Bson`](https://docs.rs/bson/0.14.0/bson/enum.Bson.html), which can be `Array`, `Boolean`, `Document`, etc. We use `match` to make sure it is `Document`.
2. I've used `?` instead of unwrap, to make use of the `Result` return type. Make sure the errors are `Into<Error>` for your `Result` type.
3. Returning `&'static str` instead of allocating a new `String` for each request.